# If $X$ is a finite dimensional space, then all linear functionals are bounded on $X$.

Tags: functional-analysis, normed-spaces

Let $X$ be a finite dimensional space. I want to prove that all linear functionals are bounded.

**MY TRIAL**

Let $\dim X=n\geq 1,$ and $\{e_i\}^{n}_{i=1}$ be a basis. Hence, there exists unique scalars $\{\alpha_i\}^{n}_{i=1}$ such that for arbitrary $x\in X,$ 
\begin{align} x=\sum^{n}_{i=1}\alpha_i e_i.\end{align}

Let $x\in X$ be arbitrary. Then,

\begin{align} |f(x)|
&=\left|f\left(\sum^{n}_{i=1}\alpha_i e_i\right)\right|\\&=\left|\sum^{n}_{i=1}\alpha_i f\left(e_i\right)\right|\\&\leq\sum^{n}_{i=1}\left|\alpha_i\right| \left|f\left(e_i\right)\right|\\&\leq \max\limits_{1\leq i\leq n}\left|\alpha_i\right|\sum^{n}_{i=1}\left|f\left(e_i\right)\right|\end{align}
Define $\|\cdot\|_0$ as $\|x\|_0=\max\limits_{1\leq i\leq n}\left|\alpha_i\right|$ which is a norm on $X$ [see [Prove that $\| \cdot \|_0$ defined by $\| x \|_0=\max\limits_{1\leq i\leq n}|\alpha_i|$ is a norm on $E$.](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3052870/prove-that-cdot-0-defined-by-x-0-max-limits-1-leq-i-leq-n-al]). Hence,
\begin{align} |f(x)|
\leq \|x\|_0\sum^{n}_{i=1}\left|f\left(e_i\right)\right|\end{align}
But [All norms defined on a finite dimensional normed linear space are equivalent](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3053327/all-norms-defined-on-a-finite-dimensional-normed-linear-space-are-equivalent), so any norm $\| \cdot \|$ defined on $E,$ is equivalent to $\| \cdot \|_0$, i.e. 
\begin{align} |f(x)|
\leq \|x\|\sum^{n}_{i=1}\left|f\left(e_i\right)\right|=K\|x\|,\;\;\text{where}\;K:=\sum^{n}_{i=1}\left|f\left(e_i\right)\right|\geq 0,\end{align}
and we are done! Please, I'm I right? Alternative proofs will be highly welcome!

Comment: The equivalence of norms is not quite as strong as you use here; you need an additional constant in your final inequality (but you can just absorb that constant into the definition of $K$).

Comment: @Mees de Vries: So, what do you say about the proof?

Comment: Your proof is fine, although I think it's easier if you use the $2-$ norm because then Cauchy-Schwarz gives the result almost immediately.

Comment: @Matematleta: That's true! Thanks for your comment!